# How to store reusable code in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-reuse

Is there any way I could save my block of code in Visual Studio 2010 and reuse it in my future web applications without having to "**Add existing files"**? Is there a feature in VS2010 that lets you globally store these blocks of code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oded pretty much covered it but I'll just reiterate here.  There are three main ways you can do this depending on how much code you want to store.

For a little code just copy the code to your Toolbox:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/zainnab/drag-and-drop-code-onto-the-toolbox)

For a little code to very large blocks of code (with some intelligence for putting in values) you can use code snippets:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/tags/tips+and+tricks/snippet/

And for lots of custom files, resources, etc... that essentially make up a new project you should use project templates:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/zainnab/roll-your-own-project-template-with-the-export-template-wizard)

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio has a feature called [code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx), which will allow you to do exactly that.

If you want a more advanced use - for whole files, sets of files and even whole projects, use [templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky.aspx).