# Implement auto code structure with visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using VS2013 for development. I want to implement such functionality that automatically write a method structure while I just write a method name with parameter and press TAB.

For example: when I write `public void testMethod(string param)` and press `TAB`, visual studio automatically writes the `TRY, CATCH and FINALLY` block and my method look like below:

```
public void testMethod(string param)
{
    try
    {

    }
    catch
    {

    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

I have googled for this but get no success, I have no idea how to achieve this task, Please guide me for the same.

Comment: Can you use ReSharper ? Because they have this built-in (It's what they call a "Live Template" in this case)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, is there any built in functionality in VS2013 that allows to create such "Custom Live Template"?

Comment: I agree with @VirtualBlackFox, ReSharper has nice [template editor](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Template_Editor.html).  If you don't have ReSharper have a look at built-in [code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx).  I used ReSharper templates only but likely built-in code snippets is enough.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio [Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx) available when you type anything in the IDE an when you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd> could also be a solution (They are harder to create than simple [text snippets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/01/24/drag-and-drop-code-onto-the-toolbox-vstiptool0007.aspx) but the experience is better in the IDE with direct auto completion)

Or you could get a [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) license and obtain the best of both world (And thousand of must-have features)

Comment: while OP asks for VS version i would also recommend to always get resharper if you don't have it already. If you're already looking into saving time when writing code resharper is the place to go. i sound like a jetbrains advertiser. sigh

Comment: We can also create the visual studio `Custom Code snippets` using `Snippet Designer` VS extension describes [here](http://www.devcurry.com/2012/02/custom-code-snippets-vs-2010.html)

Comment: @HirenKagrana nice didn't know about it!

Comment: @AndreasMüller I also find really hard to code without R#. It's too slow. But to be fair CodeRush also provide a good Code Template system.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`Code Snippet`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/01/24/drag-and-drop-code-onto-the-toolbox-vstiptool0007.aspx)

Here is a similar question: 
[`How to store reusable code`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177473/how-to-store-reusable-code-in-visual-studio-2010)